# How do I determine the value of a knife?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'd like to sell this knife I just found:
Shadow Daggers Case Hardened.
It has a good pattern and is in field tested condition.[image]

Given the value and the pattern, how can I determine a value for this knife?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42035/discussion-on-question-by-kobia-how-do-i-determine-the-value-of-a-knife).

Answer (score 2):

There are Steam groups dedicated to finding the correct values for items like Blue Gems, Crimson Webs with intricate webbings, low float items, etc. 
That would probably be the best place you can ask and get a knowledgeable answer.

Otherwise, csgo.steamanalyst.com tracks the current price as well as the price history of every item in the game. It also tells you price trends and amount of items sold. However, these are for market value items only.

CSGO trading reddit may also give you insight on how much your item is worth as people request to trade certain items for theirs and you can get a sense of what item is equivalent to another.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Please notify me. There are useless comments about TF2 (irrelevant) but not this one in my opinion